# Spring Security OAuth2 CORS issue for Authorization header

Tags: java, spring-security, cors, authorization, spring-oauth2

I use `<spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>`, `<spring.security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>`, and `<spring.security.oauth2.version>2.0.9.RELEASE</spring.security.oauth2.version>`.

I use `@CrossOrigin` to dela with CORS. For now, I want to allow all the headers and all the methods. I can use any of the other headers than Authorization without any CORS issue. But with Authorization(header to send Bearer token), I get CORS issue. I use `@CrossOrigin` annotatiion at Class level and allow all the headers as below -

```
@CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = {"*"})
```

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

How can I allow Authorization header as well as I did all other headers and avoid CORS issues?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to any configuration file:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
    urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
}
```

**EDIT**
For XML configuration, you could create a custom filter and add it to your filter chain:

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

  public void destroy() {}

}
```

XML config

```
<security:filter-chain-map>
    <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**"
        filters="
        ConcurrentSessionFilterAdmin, 
        securityContextPersistenceFilter, 
        logoutFilterAdmin, 
        usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilterAdmin, 
        basicAuthenticationFilterAdmin, 
        requestCacheAwareFilter, 
        securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter, 
        anonymousAuthenticationFilter, 
        sessionManagementFilterAdmin, 
        exceptionTranslationFilter, 
        filterSecurityInterceptorAdmin,
        CorsFilter"/>
</security:filter-chain-map>
```

Comment: I do not have Annotation configurations. Mine is XML configuration -